# Hibernate Joined Subclasses with One to Many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

How would you implement a model where an abstract superclass A has 2 subclasses, B and C. B has a bidirectional one-to-many relation with another class X.

I am using the joined subclass mapping without discriminator and with anotaions (no xml).
It works almost perfectly but the id from B is null in the X class. Can the X class get the id from the superclass? Or is it searching for an id in B.

Superclass A

```
import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

@Entity
@Table(name="t_trip")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Trip {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String name;
private boolean publicTrip;
private String description;

public Trip(){

}

public Trip(String name, String description, boolean publicTrip) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.publicTrip = publicTrip;
 }
}
```

Subclass B

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_repeatedtrip")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
 public class RepeatedTrip extends Trip {
private Date startMoment;
private String intervalType;
private int tripInterval;
private int tripFrequency;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "repeatedTrip")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
private List<TripExecutionMoment> tripExecutionMoments = new ArrayList<TripExecutionMoment>();

public RepeatedTrip() {
}

public RepeatedTrip(String name, String description,boolean publicTrip, Date startMoment,
        String intervalType, int interval, int frequency) {
    super(name, description, publicTrip);
    this.startMoment = startMoment;
    this.intervalType = intervalType;
    this.tripInterval = interval;
    this.tripFrequency = frequency;
}
}
```

OneToMany related class X

```
package be.kdg.teamB.model.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_tripexecutionmoment")
public class TripExecutionMoment {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private Date executionPointOfTime;
@ManyToOne
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@JoinColumn(name = "repeatedTripId")
private RepeatedTrip repeatedTrip;

public TripExecutionMoment() {
}

public TripExecutionMoment(Date executionPointOfTime) {

    this.executionPointOfTime = executionPointOfTime;
}

    return executionPointOfTime;
}

public void setExecutionPointOfTime(Date executionPointOfTime) {
    this.executionPointOfTime = executionPointOfTime;
}

public RepeatedTrip getRepeatedTrip() {
    return repeatedTrip;
}

public void setRepeatedTrip(RepeatedTrip repeatedTrip) {
    this.repeatedTrip = repeatedTrip;
}



 }
```

Code is called in this method:

```
public RepeatedTrip createRepeatedTrip(String name, String description,boolean publicTrip,
        Date startMoment, String intervalType, int interval,
        int frequency) {

    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    RepeatedTrip trip = new RepeatedTrip(name, description,publicTrip, startMoment,
            intervalType, interval, frequency);
    int intervalDefiner;
    Date date = trip.getStartMoment();
    switch(intervalType){
    case "D":
        intervalDefiner = Calendar.DATE;
        break;
    case "M":
        intervalDefiner = Calendar.MONTH;
        break;
    case "W":
        intervalDefiner = Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
        break;
    case "Y":
        intervalDefiner = Calendar.YEAR;
        break;
    default:
        intervalDefiner = Calendar.DATE;
        break;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<frequency;i++){

        TripExecutionMoment tripExecutionMoment = new TripExecutionMoment(date);
        trip.getTripExecutionMoments().add(tripExecutionMoment);
        date = nextDate(intervalDefiner, interval, date);
    }


    session.saveOrUpdate(trip);
    tx.commit();
    return trip;

}
```

Comment: Show us your code. You probably just forgot to initialize The `X.b` field.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I added my code (without setters and getters, which I have for all fields). How should I initialize X.b? I do not completely understand what you mean by that.

Comment: But you don't show the most interesting part. Show us the code that you use to create a TripExecutionMoment and add it to a RepeatedTrip.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added the appropriate code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I thought. You're adding the TripExecutionMoment to the RepeatedTrip:

```
trip.getTripExecutionMoments().add(tripExecutionMoment);
```

But you don't initialize the owner side of the bidirectional association, which is the only one Hibernate cares about:

```
tripExecutionMoment.setRepeatedTrip(trip);
```

Comment: Of course. I completely overlooked that. Thank you very much!